# How do i use github to host my static websites

Tags: github

i'm building a portfolio website at the moment and i have some simple html, JavaScript and angular  projects that i have already built and pushed to github as repositories.

I want to host this repositories on github so that i can provide a link on my portfolio website for visitors to click on and see my simple projects and not the source code on github.

Comment: https://pages.github.com/ ? But if you have your code on GitHub in a public repo, people are going to be able to see the source code anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You want [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/)!  This allows you to create a static site that can contain any content you'd like, and it's free.